# How to configure CodeIgniter connection on OpenShift?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, openshift

I just finished my php application so I decided to try it on my online account OpenShift. I created a new application and I imported `PHP 5.3, MySQL` and `phpMyAdmin`. I then uploaded via filezilla my application in the `app-root/data/Calendar`, I think it's the right folder where to upload the projects. Within the `Calendar` folder is my php application. 
I then inserted these credentials in the configuration.php file:

```
<?php
class SystemConfiguration 
{
    // General Settings
    public static $base_url    = 'first-johncloun.rhcloud.com/Calendar/';

    // Database Settings
    public static $db_host     = 'mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/';
    public static $db_name     = 'first';
    public static $db_username = 'admisawhiN';
    public static $db_password = '*****';

}
```

Are the credentials for my database. So I put this url `first-johncloun.rhcloud.com/Calendar/` to connect to my application but is displayed:

> 404 Page not found

What did I do wrong? Someone could help me? I'm new on OpenShift.

Comment: I'd suppose that you use a special quick start/deploy service on Openshift, here's a pre-made package for CodeIgniter: https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/123-codeigniter-3-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'd like to point out that you should really be using `git` to deploy your application, see: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-modifying-applications.html

However, if you really want to stick to ftp upload, according to the [openshift documentation](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-sftp-and-openshift/) you should upload your app to:

```
/app-root/repo/php
```